# Removing all but one item from Controls

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, controls

I currently have a `Sharepoint 2010` web part which includes several labels. I want to programmatically remove all but one of these labels.

I tried the code below but got a `System.InvalidOperationException` because obviously one can't modify a collection while iterating through it. However, I don't know how else to try this.

```
    private void clearLabels()
    {
        foreach (Control cont in this.Controls)
            if (cont is Label && cont.ID != "error")
                this.Controls.Remove(cont);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over it backwards.

```
for(int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (this.Controls[i] is Label && this.Controls[i].ID != "error")
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(this.Controls[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct as to why you are getting the error. The following using Linq and ToArray() to solve the problem:

```
private void clearLabels()
    {
        foreach (from cont in this.Controls).ToArray()
            if (cont is Label && cont.ID != "error")
                this.Controls.Remove(cont);
    }
```

I would refactor this even further to:

```
private void clearLabels() {

    foreach (from cont in this.Controls 
             where cont is Label && cont.ID != "error"
            ).ToArray()
        this.Controls.Remove(cont);
}
```